# Need to correct spacing within my script output

Tags: r

I am having trouble in Rstudio once again, my data is acting up somehow going through the interpreter. Tyring to get results from each single value in the vector, but it gives me the whole group of vectors values with each of the outcomes. The script looks like this:

```r
#Creating Function
Grams <- c(0.96, 1.51, 2.17, 3.85, 4.45,6.02)
Diam <- function(weight){(2/2.54*(weight/0.92*4/3*3.14159)^1/3)}

#Testing if it works with a specific gram of measurement
Diam(1.51)

#For Loop
for (weight in Grams){
  IceCube <- Diam(weight)
  cat( Grams,'\n', "of", IceCube, "is it sphere diameter", "\n" )
}
```

The interpretation is this:

```
0.96 1.51 2.17 3.85 4.45 6.02 
 of 1.14722 is it sphere diameter 
0.96 1.51 2.17 3.85 4.45 6.02 
 of 1.804481 is it sphere diameter 
0.96 1.51 2.17 3.85 4.45 6.02 
 of 2.593195 is it sphere diameter 
0.96 1.51 2.17 3.85 4.45 6.02 
 of 4.60083 is it sphere diameter 
0.96 1.51 2.17 3.85 4.45 6.02 
 of 5.317842 is it sphere diameter 
0.96 1.51 2.17 3.85 4.45 6.02 
 of 7.194025 is it sphere diameter
```

Comment: Should you instead use `cat(weight, '\n', ...)`?

Comment: No, had to use paste and change Grams into weight.

Comment: Huh? `paste` is not required. I literally pasted your code and replaced `cat(Grams` with `cat(weight` and it worked.

Comment: Regardless, you asked why all of `Grams` was being printed each time ... it's because you explicitly tell R to print all of `Grams` each time. Perhaps both akrun and I are completely missing your point; please add your expected output to your question.

Answer (score 1):

We are calling a for each loop where each element of 'Grams' is looped and instead of 'Grams' should call 'weight'. Also, wrap with `paste`

```
 for (weight in Grams){
  IceCube <- Diam(weight)
  cat( paste(weight,'\n', "of", IceCube, "is it sphere diameter"), "\n" )
}
```

Comment: Why use paste and change Grams to weight knowing that my Grams has my stored vectors.

Comment: @JasonBorne your description in the post is `Tyring to get results from each single value in the vector, but it gives me the whole group of vectors values with each of the outcomes.` which is corrected with the above code.  `paste` I used only to make things flexible